# Difference of type() function in Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

When trying the following script in Python 2,

```
a = 200  
print type(a)
```

its output is

```
<type 'int'>
```

and in Python 3, the script

```
a = 200
print (type(a))
```

its output is,

```
<class 'int'>
```

What may be the reason for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the days of yore, built-in types such as `int` and `dict` and `list` were very different from types built with `class`. You could not subclass built-in types for example.

Gradually, in successive Python 2.x releases, the differences between `class` types and builtin types have eroded; the introduction of *new-style classes* (inheriting from `object`) in Python 2.2 was one such (major) step. See [*Unifying types and classes in Python 2.2*](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/).

Removing the use of `type` in built-in type representations is just the last step in that process. There was no reason anymore to use the name `type` anymore.

In other words, between Python 2.7 and 3.x this is a *cosmetic* change, nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

`type` isn't behaving any differently. They just changed things so all classes show up as `<class ...>` instead of `<type ...>`, regardless of whether the class is a built-in type like `int` or a class created with the `class` statement. It's one of the final steps of the elimination of the class/type distinction, a process that began back in 2.2.